# Closing UITableViewController when the keyboard covers cells causes crash

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a UITableViewController with custom cells for static and editable text. Standard stuff, nothing fancy.

The cell data is stored so that when cells are reused, the data is placed back inside them.

The problem is this: when the user has the cursor in a UITextField cell and the keyboard's up, the keyboard is covering three rows in the table view. There's a cancel button at the top of the view controller which is supposed to dismiss the view controller. When I call dismissModalViewController, the keyboard hides, but the UITableViewController wants to refresh the rows that were under the keyboard while the view's going away. However, the view's already in its death throes and I get a crash because the table view's trying to call cellForRowAtIndexPath to update rows that are in the process of being removed.

I tried waiting for the keyboard to hide. No good.

I tried resigning the first responder so the keyboard goes away and updates the rows first before dismissing the view controller, but there's nothing I can find that tells me the data's finished updating.

What I need is some event that tells me that the table is finished updating, or tell the table view to not ask for data from the delegate, or tell the table view to not update when the keyboard is going away.

Or there's something simple I'm missing.

Any help?

Comment: What is the exact error you get when it crashes?

Comment: -[CABasicAnimation length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb579130
2013-02-21 17:23:08.765 InsureIt[33064:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CABasicAnimation length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb579130'
In the stack, it's calling setText:

Comment: How do you know the crash is because the table tries to call cellFForRowAtIndexPath then?

Comment: I put an NSLog in cFRAIP and removed the call to close the window, but still hide the keyboard. iOS refreshes the cells under the keyboard when it disappears and that's where the app crashes, trying to redraw cells that have been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not more cells, i advice you to make a different Reusable Identifier for each cell.That very better to save the state of cells after being dequeued

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem. Inside cellForRowAtIndexPath, I was setting text inside a UITextField for pointers that may no longer exist. What I did to fix the problem was still create the cell, but before setting the text inside it, I checked if the Cancel button was pressed and if it was, return the empty cell.

I was hoping there'd be a better solution such as waiting for the cells to finish updating, but that doesn't seem to be happening.